# Calculating $ \sum_{ k=1}^n (-1)^k k $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I've got two sums here

$ \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k k  $
and $ \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k k^2 $

I need to solve them through term isolation.
I struggle to find anything similar.
So I am asking you for help; do you have any ideas or approaches?

Comment: Just look at the even and odd summands separately.

Comment: For the $k$ terms, consider each consecutive pair...

Comment: A similar idea — grouping pairs of terms as far as possible — works for the second sum too.

Comment: I did consider that as well. Though the "term isolation" confuses me. Does that just mean consindering each consecutive pair?

Comment: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2137234), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2069385), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388388)...

Answer (score 1):

Try writing out some terms as $n$ grows.

$$\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kk\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=\{-1,1,-2,2,-3,3\ldots\}$$

You have the ceiling of $n/2$ alternating negative and positive.

$$\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kk^2\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}=\{-1,3,-6,10,-15,21\ldots\}$$

You have the triangular numbers $n(n+1)/2$ alternating negative and positive.

If you need a proof, there are good ideas in the comments.